# Ruby on Rails app categories not working or sorting on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, heroku-postgres

I created Products that each have a category based on their gender. Everything works fine in my localhost but in Heroku when I press each category it doesn't sort out the products like in my localhost. The browser shows -> herokuapp.com/products?category=Trajes+de+Ba%C3%B1o but doesn't do what its suppose to.

**My Products controller:**

```
  def index
    if params.key?(:category)
      @category = Category.find_by_name(params[:category])
      @pagy, @products = pagy(Product.where(category: @category))
    else
      @pagy, @products = pagy(Product.search(params[:search]), items: 9)
    end
  end

  def women
    if params.key?(:category)
      @category = Category.find_by_name(params[:category])
      @women_product_items = Product.where(category: @category)
    else
      @women_product_items = Product.women.search(params[:search])
    end
  end

  def men
    if params.key?(:category)
      @category = Category.find_by_name(params[:category])
      @men_product_items = Product.where(category: @category)
    else
      @men_product_items = Product.men.search(params[:search])
    end
  end

  def kids
    if params.key?(:category)
      @category = Category.find_by_name(params[:category])
      @kids_product_items = Product.where(category: @category)
    else
      @kids_product_items = Product.kids.search(params[:search])
    end
  end
```

**Here is everything that appeared in heroku logs:**

```
2019-09-06T02:44:31.278950+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-09-06T02:44:31.278862 #4] DEBUG -- : [a5f8d022-718a-4776-868f-f5466372df4d]   Category Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories"
2019-09-06T02:44:31.281137+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-09-06T02:44:31.281040 #4] DEBUG -- : [a5f8d022-718a-4776-868f-f5466372df4d]   Category Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."display_in_women" = $1  [["display_in_women", true]]
2019-09-06T02:44:31.282908+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-09-06T02:44:31.282824 #4] DEBUG -- : [a5f8d022-718a-4776-868f-f5466372df4d]   Category Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."display_in_men" = $1  [["display_in_men", true]]
2019-09-06T02:44:31.285129+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-09-06T02:44:31.285054 #4] DEBUG -- : [a5f8d022-718a-4776-868f-f5466372df4d]   Category Load (1.5ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."display_in_kids" = $1  [["display_in_kids", true]]
2019-09-06T02:44:31.287025+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-09-06T02:44:31.286953 #4] DEBUG -- : [a5f8d022-718a-4776-868f-f5466372df4d]    (1.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT  1 AS one FROM "products" LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2) subquery_for_count  [["LIMIT", 2], ["OFFSET", 0]]
2019-09-06T02:44:31.287960+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-06T02:44:31.287855 #4]  INFO -- : [a5f8d022-718a-4776-868f-f5466372df4d]   Rendered products/index.html.erb within layouts/application (18.8ms)
2019-09-06T02:44:31.288971+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-06T02:44:31.288898 #4]  INFO -- : [a5f8d022-718a-4776-868f-f5466372df4d]   Rendered shared/_message.html.erb (0.1ms)
2019-09-06T02:44:31.289409+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-06T02:44:31.289337 #4]  INFO -- : [a5f8d022-718a-4776-868f-f5466372df4d]   Rendered shared/_footer.html.erb (0.2ms)
2019-09-06T02:44:31.289688+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-06T02:44:31.289617 #4]  INFO -- : [a5f8d022-718a-4776-868f-f5466372df4d] Completed 200 OK in 26ms (Views: 12.9ms | ActiveRecord: 10.3ms)
2019-09-06T02:44:33.867737+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/products?category=Vestidos" host=rv10online1.herokuapp.com request_id=b54d57b8-b1c1-45dd-8b48-6227307f7ecc fwd="190.186.94.69" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=34ms status=200 bytes=17170 protocol=https
2019-09-06T02:44:33.833194+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-06T02:44:33.833060 #4]  INFO -- : [b54d57b8-b1c1-45dd-8b48-6227307f7ecc] Started GET "/products?category=Vestidos" for 190.186.94.69 at 2019-09-06 02:44:33 +0000
2019-09-06T02:44:33.834328+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-06T02:44:33.834239 #4]  INFO -- : [b54d57b8-b1c1-45dd-8b48-6227307f7ecc] Processing by ProductsController#index as HTML
2019-09-06T02:44:33.834433+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-06T02:44:33.834346 #4]  INFO -- : [b54d57b8-b1c1-45dd-8b48-6227307f7ecc]   Parameters: {"category"=>"Vestidos"}
2019-09-06T02:44:33.838292+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-09-06T02:44:33.838202 #4] DEBUG -- : [b54d57b8-b1c1-45dd-8b48-6227307f7ecc]   Cart Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "carts".* FROM "carts" WHERE "carts"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2019-09-06T02:44:33.842374+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-09-06T02:44:33.842258 #4] DEBUG -- : [b54d57b8-b1c1-45dd-8b48-6227307f7ecc]   Category Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."name" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["name", "Vestidos"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2019-09-06T02:44:33.844310+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-09-06T02:44:33.844218 #4] DEBUG -- : [b54d57b8-b1c1-45dd-8b48-6227307f7ecc]    (1.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "products" WHERE "products"."category" = $1  [["category", "2"]]
2019-09-06T02:44:33.844920+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-06T02:44:33.844840 #4]  INFO -- : [b54d57b8-b1c1-45dd-8b48-6227307f7ecc]   Rendering products/index.html.erb within layouts/application
2019-09-06T02:44:33.847723+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-09-06T02:44:33.847634 #4] DEBUG -- : [b54d57b8-b1c1-45dd-8b48-6227307f7ecc]   ProductItem Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "product_items".* FROM "product_items" WHERE "product_items"."cart_id" = $1  [["cart_id", 1]]
2019-09-06T02:44:33.849519+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-09-06T02:44:33.849407 #4] DEBUG -- : [b54d57b8-b1c1-45dd-8b48-6227307f7ecc]   Product Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2019-09-06T02:44:33.850437+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-06T02:44:33.850364 #4]  INFO -- : [b54d57b8-b1c1-45dd-8b48-6227307f7ecc]   Rendered shared/_header.html.erb (5.3ms)
2019-09-06T02:44:33.852025+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-09-06T02:44:33.851948 #4] DEBUG -- : [b54d57b8-b1c1-45dd-8b48-6227307f7ecc]   Category Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories"
2019-09-06T02:44:33.854255+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-09-06T02:44:33.854171 #4] DEBUG -- : [b54d57b8-b1c1-45dd-8b48-6227307f7ecc]   Category Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."display_in_women" = $1  [["display_in_women", true]]
2019-09-06T02:44:33.856209+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-09-06T02:44:33.856105 #4] DEBUG -- : [b54d57b8-b1c1-45dd-8b48-6227307f7ecc]   Category Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."display_in_men" = $1  [["display_in_men", true]]
2019-09-06T02:44:33.858104+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-09-06T02:44:33.857965 #4] DEBUG -- : [b54d57b8-b1c1-45dd-8b48-6227307f7ecc]   Category Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."display_in_kids" = $1  [["display_in_kids", true]]
2019-09-06T02:44:33.860343+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-09-06T02:44:33.860241 #4] DEBUG -- : [b54d57b8-b1c1-45dd-8b48-6227307f7ecc]    (1.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT  1 AS one FROM "products" WHERE "products"."category" = $1 LIMIT $2 OFFSET $3) subquery_for_count  [["category", "2"], ["LIMIT", 20], ["OFFSET", 0]]
2019-09-06T02:44:33.861429+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-06T02:44:33.861337 #4]  INFO -- : [b54d57b8-b1c1-45dd-8b48-6227307f7ecc]   Rendered products/index.html.erb within layouts/application (16.3ms)
2019-09-06T02:44:33.862430+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-06T02:44:33.862360 #4]  INFO -- : [b54d57b8-b1c1-45dd-8b48-6227307f7ecc]   Rendered shared/_message.html.erb (0.1ms)
2019-09-06T02:44:33.862898+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-06T02:44:33.862823 #4]  INFO -- : [b54d57b8-b1c1-45dd-8b48-6227307f7ecc]   Rendered shared/_footer.html.erb (0.2ms)
2019-09-06T02:44:33.863171+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-06T02:44:33.863109 #4]  INFO -- : [b54d57b8-b1c1-45dd-8b48-6227307f7ecc] Completed 200 OK in 29ms (Views: 10.7ms | ActiveRecord: 11.1ms)
2019-09-06T02:44:36.214279+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-06T02:44:36.214158 #4]  INFO -- : [93681d9a-5f2d-4931-97ee-4337ae9df01d] Started GET "/products?category=Trajes+de+Ba%C3%B1o" for 190.186.94.69 at 2019-09-06 02:44:36 +0000
2019-09-06T02:44:36.215542+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-06T02:44:36.215462 #4]  INFO -- : [93681d9a-5f2d-4931-97ee-4337ae9df01d] Processing by ProductsController#index as HTML
2019-09-06T02:44:36.215661+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-06T02:44:36.215585 #4]  INFO -- : [93681d9a-5f2d-4931-97ee-4337ae9df01d]   Parameters: {"category"=>"Trajes de Baño"}
2019-09-06T02:44:36.219518+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-09-06T02:44:36.219446 #4] DEBUG -- : [93681d9a-5f2d-4931-97ee-4337ae9df01d]   Cart Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "carts".* FROM "carts" WHERE "carts"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2019-09-06T02:44:36.221116+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-09-06T02:44:36.221047 #4] DEBUG -- : [93681d9a-5f2d-4931-97ee-4337ae9df01d]   Category Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."name" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["name", "Trajes de Baño"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2019-09-06T02:44:36.223098+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-09-06T02:44:36.222964 #4] DEBUG -- : [93681d9a-5f2d-4931-97ee-4337ae9df01d]    (1.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "products" WHERE "products"."category" = $1  [["category", "1"]]
2019-09-06T02:44:36.223772+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-06T02:44:36.223657 #4]  INFO -- : [93681d9a-5f2d-4931-97ee-4337ae9df01d]   Rendering products/index.html.erb within layouts/application
2019-09-06T02:44:36.226326+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-09-06T02:44:36.226255 #4] DEBUG -- : [93681d9a-5f2d-4931-97ee-4337ae9df01d]   ProductItem Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "product_items".* FROM "product_items" WHERE "product_items"."cart_id" = $1  [["cart_id", 1]]
2019-09-06T02:44:36.228395+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-09-06T02:44:36.228293 #4] DEBUG -- : [93681d9a-5f2d-4931-97ee-4337ae9df01d]   Product Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2019-09-06T02:44:36.229854+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-06T02:44:36.229750 #4]  INFO -- : [93681d9a-5f2d-4931-97ee-4337ae9df01d]   Rendered shared/_header.html.erb (5.8ms)
2019-09-06T02:44:36.231757+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-09-06T02:44:36.231670 #4] DEBUG -- : [93681d9a-5f2d-4931-97ee-4337ae9df01d]   Category Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories"
2019-09-06T02:44:36.233896+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-09-06T02:44:36.233816 #4] DEBUG -- : [93681d9a-5f2d-4931-97ee-4337ae9df01d]   Category Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."display_in_women" = $1  [["display_in_women", true]]
2019-09-06T02:44:36.235653+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-09-06T02:44:36.235558 #4] DEBUG -- : [93681d9a-5f2d-4931-97ee-4337ae9df01d]   Category Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."display_in_men" = $1  [["display_in_men", true]]
2019-09-06T02:44:36.237335+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-09-06T02:44:36.237254 #4] DEBUG -- : [93681d9a-5f2d-4931-97ee-4337ae9df01d]   Category Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."display_in_kids" = $1  [["display_in_kids", true]]
2019-09-06T02:44:36.239486+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-09-06T02:44:36.239407 #4] DEBUG -- : [93681d9a-5f2d-4931-97ee-4337ae9df01d]    (1.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT  1 AS one FROM "products" WHERE "products"."category" = $1 LIMIT $2 OFFSET $3) subquery_for_count  [["category", "1"], ["LIMIT", 2], ["OFFSET", 0]]
2019-09-06T02:44:36.240293+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-06T02:44:36.240219 #4]  INFO -- : [93681d9a-5f2d-4931-97ee-4337ae9df01d]   Rendered products/index.html.erb within layouts/application (16.4ms)
2019-09-06T02:44:36.241070+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-06T02:44:36.240974 #4]  INFO -- : [93681d9a-5f2d-4931-97ee-4337ae9df01d]   Rendered shared/_message.html.erb (0.0ms)
2019-09-06T02:44:36.241494+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-06T02:44:36.241422 #4]  INFO -- : [93681d9a-5f2d-4931-97ee-4337ae9df01d]   Rendered shared/_footer.html.erb (0.2ms)
2019-09-06T02:44:36.241755+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-06T02:44:36.241685 #4]  INFO -- : [93681d9a-5f2d-4931-97ee-4337ae9df01d] Completed 200 OK in 26ms (Views: 10.9ms | ActiveRecord: 10.6ms)
2019-09-06T02:44:36.246559+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/products?category=Trajes+de+Ba%C3%B1o" host=rv10online1.herokuapp.com request_id=93681d9a-5f2d-4931-97ee-4337ae9df01d fwd="190.186.94.69" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=32ms status=200 bytes=17172 protocol=https
2019-09-06T02:46:18.111771+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-06T02:46:18.111631 #4]  INFO -- : [e1f7c77d-79e4-452b-ada4-79f6ae54d7c3] Started GET "/" for 190.186.94.69 at 2019-09-06 02:46:18 +0000
2019-09-06T02:46:18.113344+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-06T02:46:18.113249 #4]  INFO -- : [e1f7c77d-79e4-452b-ada4-79f6ae54d7c3] Processing by PagesController#index as HTML
2019-09-06T02:46:18.117709+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-09-06T02:46:18.117611 #4] DEBUG -- : [e1f7c77d-79e4-452b-ada4-79f6ae54d7c3]   Cart Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "carts".* FROM "carts" WHERE "carts"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2019-09-06T02:46:18.120089+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-06T02:46:18.119991 #4]  INFO -- : [e1f7c77d-79e4-452b-ada4-79f6ae54d7c3]   Rendering pages/index.html.erb within layouts/application
2019-09-06T02:46:18.128335+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-09-06T02:46:18.128208 #4] DEBUG -- : [e1f7c77d-79e4-452b-ada4-79f6ae54d7c3]   ProductItem Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "product_items".* FROM "product_items" WHERE "product_items"."cart_id" = $1  [["cart_id", 1]]
2019-09-06T02:46:18.130683+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-09-06T02:46:18.130598 #4] DEBUG -- : [e1f7c77d-79e4-452b-ada4-79f6ae54d7c3]   Product Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2019-09-06T02:46:18.133528+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-06T02:46:18.133432 #4]  INFO -- : [e1f7c77d-79e4-452b-ada4-79f6ae54d7c3]   Rendered shared/_navbarhome.html.erb (11.4ms)
2019-09-06T02:46:18.134039+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-06T02:46:18.133948 #4]  INFO -- : [e1f7c77d-79e4-452b-ada4-79f6ae54d7c3]   Rendered pages/index.html.erb within layouts/application (13.8ms)
2019-09-06T02:46:18.135483+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-06T02:46:18.135378 #4]  INFO -- : [e1f7c77d-79e4-452b-ada4-79f6ae54d7c3]   Rendered shared/_message.html.erb (0.1ms)
2019-09-06T02:46:18.136125+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-06T02:46:18.136027 #4]  INFO -- : [e1f7c77d-79e4-452b-ada4-79f6ae54d7c3]   Rendered shared/_footer.html.erb (0.3ms)
2019-09-06T02:46:18.136649+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-06T02:46:18.136527 #4]  INFO -- : [e1f7c77d-79e4-452b-ada4-79f6ae54d7c3] Completed 200 OK in 23ms (Views: 14.8ms | ActiveRecord: 3.4ms)
2019-09-06T02:46:18.141534+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=rv10online1.herokuapp.com request_id=e1f7c77d-79e4-452b-ada4-79f6ae54d7c3 fwd="190.186.94.69" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30ms status=200 bytes=27460 protocol=https
2019-09-06T02:46:19.210969+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=rv10online1.herokuapp.com request_id=8eb72357-1ffb-42e5-b5d4-5db8bd58f2f4 fwd="190.186.94.69" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=48 protocol=https
2019-09-06T02:46:28.096164+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/products" host=rv10online1.herokuapp.com request_id=63de8dcb-4c8a-45ca-b43a-216a8b640fc7 fwd="190.186.94.69" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=29ms status=200 bytes=17168 protocol=https
2019-09-06T02:46:28.066874+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-06T02:46:28.066768 #4]  INFO -- : [63de8dcb-4c8a-45ca-b43a-216a8b640fc7] Started GET "/products" for 190.186.94.69 at 2019-09-06 02:46:28 +0000
2019-09-06T02:46:28.067767+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-06T02:46:28.067691 #4]  INFO -- : [63de8dcb-4c8a-45ca-b43a-216a8b640fc7] Processing by ProductsController#index as HTML
2019-09-06T02:46:28.071557+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-09-06T02:46:28.071477 #4] DEBUG -- : [63de8dcb-4c8a-45ca-b43a-216a8b640fc7]   Cart Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "carts".* FROM "carts" WHERE "carts"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2019-09-06T02:46:28.073373+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-09-06T02:46:28.073301 #4] DEBUG -- : [63de8dcb-4c8a-45ca-b43a-216a8b640fc7]    (1.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "products"
2019-09-06T02:46:28.074116+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-06T02:46:28.074048 #4]  INFO -- : [63de8dcb-4c8a-45ca-b43a-216a8b640fc7]   Rendering products/index.html.erb within layouts/application
2019-09-06T02:46:28.076913+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-09-06T02:46:28.076825 #4] DEBUG -- : [63de8dcb-4c8a-45ca-b43a-216a8b640fc7]   ProductItem Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "product_items".* FROM "product_items" WHERE "product_items"."cart_id" = $1  [["cart_id", 1]]
2019-09-06T02:46:28.078737+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-09-06T02:46:28.078671 #4] DEBUG -- : [63de8dcb-4c8a-45ca-b43a-216a8b640fc7]   Product Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2019-09-06T02:46:28.079737+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-06T02:46:28.079669 #4]  INFO -- : [63de8dcb-4c8a-45ca-b43a-216a8b640fc7]   Rendered shared/_header.html.erb (5.4ms)
2019-09-06T02:46:28.081394+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-09-06T02:46:28.081306 #4] DEBUG -- : [63de8dcb-4c8a-45ca-b43a-216a8b640fc7]   Category Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories"
2019-09-06T02:46:28.084184+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-09-06T02:46:28.084082 #4] DEBUG -- : [63de8dcb-4c8a-45ca-b43a-216a8b640fc7]   Category Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."display_in_women" = $1  [["display_in_women", true]]
2019-09-06T02:46:28.085929+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-09-06T02:46:28.085861 #4] DEBUG -- : [63de8dcb-4c8a-45ca-b43a-216a8b640fc7]   Category Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."display_in_men" = $1  [["display_in_men", true]]
2019-09-06T02:46:28.087509+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-09-06T02:46:28.087417 #4] DEBUG -- : [63de8dcb-4c8a-45ca-b43a-216a8b640fc7]   Category Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."display_in_kids" = $1  [["display_in_kids", true]]
2019-09-06T02:46:28.089611+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-09-06T02:46:28.089535 #4] DEBUG -- : [63de8dcb-4c8a-45ca-b43a-216a8b640fc7]    (1.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT  1 AS one FROM "products" LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2) subquery_for_count  [["LIMIT", 2], ["OFFSET", 0]]
2019-09-06T02:46:28.090452+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-06T02:46:28.090372 #4]  INFO -- : [63de8dcb-4c8a-45ca-b43a-216a8b640fc7]   Rendered products/index.html.erb within layouts/application (16.2ms)
2019-09-06T02:46:28.091306+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-06T02:46:28.091224 #4]  INFO -- : [63de8dcb-4c8a-45ca-b43a-216a8b640fc7]   Rendered shared/_message.html.erb (0.1ms)
2019-09-06T02:46:28.091769+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-06T02:46:28.091697 #4]  INFO -- : [63de8dcb-4c8a-45ca-b43a-216a8b640fc7]   Rendered shared/_footer.html.erb (0.2ms)
2019-09-06T02:46:28.092062+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-06T02:46:28.091992 #4]  INFO -- : [63de8dcb-4c8a-45ca-b43a-216a8b640fc7] Completed 200 OK in 24ms (Views: 10.8ms | ActiveRecord: 9.5ms)
2019-09-06T02:46:31.169628+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-06T02:46:31.169479 #4]  INFO -- : [c74c9d36-41d7-4976-95aa-0274c995de7e] Started GET "/products?category=Trajes+de+Ba%C3%B1o" for 190.186.94.69 at 2019-09-06 02:46:31 +0000
2019-09-06T02:46:31.170479+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-06T02:46:31.170391 #4]  INFO -- : [c74c9d36-41d7-4976-95aa-0274c995de7e] Processing by ProductsController#index as HTML
2019-09-06T02:46:31.170564+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-06T02:46:31.170481 #4]  INFO -- : [c74c9d36-41d7-4976-95aa-0274c995de7e]   Parameters: {"category"=>"Trajes de Baño"}
2019-09-06T02:46:31.174169+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-09-06T02:46:31.174093 #4] DEBUG -- : [c74c9d36-41d7-4976-95aa-0274c995de7e]   Cart Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "carts".* FROM "carts" WHERE "carts"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2019-09-06T02:46:31.175844+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-09-06T02:46:31.175750 #4] DEBUG -- : [c74c9d36-41d7-4976-95aa-0274c995de7e]   Category Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."name" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["name", "Trajes de Baño"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2019-09-06T02:46:31.177865+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-09-06T02:46:31.177767 #4] DEBUG -- : [c74c9d36-41d7-4976-95aa-0274c995de7e]    (1.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "products" WHERE "products"."category" = $1  [["category", "1"]]
2019-09-06T02:46:31.178481+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-06T02:46:31.178408 #4]  INFO -- : [c74c9d36-41d7-4976-95aa-0274c995de7e]   Rendering products/index.html.erb within layouts/application
2019-09-06T02:46:31.181097+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-09-06T02:46:31.180999 #4] DEBUG -- : [c74c9d36-41d7-4976-95aa-0274c995de7e]   ProductItem Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "product_items".* FROM "product_items" WHERE "product_items"."cart_id" = $1  [["cart_id", 1]]
2019-09-06T02:46:31.183479+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-09-06T02:46:31.183400 #4] DEBUG -- : [c74c9d36-41d7-4976-95aa-0274c995de7e]   Product Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2019-09-06T02:46:31.184669+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-06T02:46:31.184598 #4]  INFO -- : [c74c9d36-41d7-4976-95aa-0274c995de7e]   Rendered shared/_header.html.erb (6.0ms)
2019-09-06T02:46:31.186785+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-09-06T02:46:31.186685 #4] DEBUG -- : [c74c9d36-41d7-4976-95aa-0274c995de7e]   Category Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories"
2019-09-06T02:46:31.189217+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-09-06T02:46:31.189127 #4] DEBUG -- : [c74c9d36-41d7-4976-95aa-0274c995de7e]   Category Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."display_in_women" = $1  [["display_in_women", true]]
2019-09-06T02:46:31.191143+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-09-06T02:46:31.191051 #4] DEBUG -- : [c74c9d36-41d7-4976-95aa-0274c995de7e]   Category Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."display_in_men" = $1  [["display_in_men", true]]
2019-09-06T02:46:31.192982+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-09-06T02:46:31.192885 #4] DEBUG -- : [c74c9d36-41d7-4976-95aa-0274c995de7e]   Category Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."display_in_kids" = $1  [["display_in_kids", true]]
2019-09-06T02:46:31.195143+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-09-06T02:46:31.195065 #4] DEBUG -- : [c74c9d36-41d7-4976-95aa-0274c995de7e]    (1.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT  1 AS one FROM "products" WHERE "products"."category" = $1 LIMIT $2 OFFSET $3) subquery_for_count  [["category", "1"], ["LIMIT", 2], ["OFFSET", 0]]
2019-09-06T02:46:31.196208+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-06T02:46:31.196142 #4]  INFO -- : [c74c9d36-41d7-4976-95aa-0274c995de7e]   Rendered products/index.html.erb within layouts/application (17.6ms)
2019-09-06T02:46:31.197537+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-06T02:46:31.197460 #4]  INFO -- : [c74c9d36-41d7-4976-95aa-0274c995de7e]   Rendered shared/_message.html.erb (0.1ms)
2019-09-06T02:46:31.198067+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-06T02:46:31.197993 #4]  INFO -- : [c74c9d36-41d7-4976-95aa-0274c995de7e]   Rendered shared/_footer.html.erb (0.3ms)
2019-09-06T02:46:31.198405+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-06T02:46:31.198323 #4]  INFO -- : [c74c9d36-41d7-4976-95aa-0274c995de7e] Completed 200 OK in 28ms (Views: 12.8ms | ActiveRecord: 10.6ms)
2019-09-06T02:46:31.202707+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/products?category=Trajes+de+Ba%C3%B1o" host=rv10online1.herokuapp.com request_id=c74c9d36-41d7-4976-95aa-0274c995de7e fwd="190.186.94.69" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=33ms status=200 bytes=17168 protocol=https
```

Product page view

```
<%= render "shared/header" %>
<div class="containe-fluid" style="background-color: #ebebeb; padding-bottom: 2% !important;">
   <div class="caption-content text-center">
      <div class="font-alt mb-30 titan-title-size-1 ">
         <h2 style="font-size:100px;"><%= image_tag "rv10.png", height: 70 %></h2>
      </div>
      <div class="font-alt mb-30 titan-title-size-4">
         <p class="description">50% DE DESCUENTO EN TODO</p>
      </div>
      <div class="font-alt mb-40 titan-title-size-1">
         <p class="description">
            Usa el codigo <b>SUMMER50</b>, Oferta EXPIRA en 
            <b>
         <p id="demo"></p></b></p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top:5%; ">
   <div class="wrap">
      <div class="left">
         <!-- Navbar for categories -->
         <div class="categories" style="display:inline-block;">
            <b>Buscar por Codigo:</b> <br>
            <br>
            <%= form_tag products_path, :method => 'get' do %>
            <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
            <% end %>
            <b class="titulos">Todas Las Categorias</b> <br>
            <%= link_to 'Todas las categorias', products_path %><br>
            <% Category.all.each do |cat| %>
            <%= link_to cat.name, products_path(category: cat.name) %>
            <br>
            <% end %>
            <!-- end -->
            <br>
            <b class="titulos">MUJERES</b> <br>
            <% Category.where(display_in_women: true).each do |cat| %>
            <%= link_to cat.name, products_path(category: cat.name)%>
            <br>
            <% end %>
            <br>
            <b class="titulos">HOMBRES</b> <br>
            <% Category.where(display_in_men: true).each do |cat| %>
            <%= link_to cat.name, products_path(category: cat.name)%>
            <br>
            <% end %>
            <br>
            <b class="titulos">KIDS</b> <br>
            <% Category.where(display_in_kids: true).each do |cat| %>
            <%= link_to cat.name, products_path(category: cat.name)%>
            <br>
            <% end %>
         </div>
         <br>
         <br>
         <br>
         <br>
      </div>
      <!-- close left -->
      <h4 class="titulo"><b>TODOS LOS PRODUCTOS</b></h4>
      <div class="searcher">
         <h5>La mejor version de ti mismo. Moda boliviana inspirada en gente activa.</h5>
      </div>
      <br>
      <!-- productos -->
      <%== pagy_nav(@pagy) %>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <div class="quantityproducts">Productos ( <%= @products.count %> )</div>
      <hr>
      <div class="row">
         <% cache do %>
         <% @products.each do |product| %>
         <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="product-grid2">
               <div class="product-image2">
                  <a><%= cl_image_tag product.photo %></a>
                  <ul class="social">
                     <li><a href="#" data-tip="Quick View"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a></li>
                     <li><a href="#" data-tip="Add to Cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></a></li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
               <div class="product-content">
                  <h3 class="title"><a href="#"><%= link_to product.title, product %></a></h3>
                  <% if product.sale_price == 0 %>
                  <p style="font-size:12px;"><%= number_to_currency_bo product.price %></p>
                  <% else %>
                  <p style="display: inline-block; font-size: 12px;"><i style="text-decoration: line-through;"><%= number_to_currency_bo product.sale_price %></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<b style="font-weight: 600;"><%= number_to_currency_bo product.price %></b></p>
                  <% end %>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <% end %>
         <% end %>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
<%== pagy_nav(@pagy) %>
<hr>
</div>
</div>
<!-- end productos -->
```

Comment: It would be easier to help if you can share the log file when sending request.

Comment: Sure! I just added my heroku logs on the page. thank you.

Comment: The controller does work `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "products" WHERE "products"."category" = $1  [["category", "2"]]`, what you need to do next is to check your view file. You can check it yourself or upload it here so we can help check as well.

Comment: I suspect that your view always render `Product.all`, rather than `@products`, can you share your view file?

Comment: Sure! I just uploaded it :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm sure you have cache issue. Please remove cache block and you should see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have the products assigned to a category

according to this line, heroku is doing the query well

> 2019-09-06T02: 44: 33.844310 + 00: 00 app [web.1]: D, [2019-09-06T02:
>   44: 33.844218 # 4] DEBUG -: [b54d57b8-b1c1-45dd-8b48-6227307f7ecc]
>   (1.1ms) SELECT COUNT (*) FROM "products" WHERE "products". "Category"
>   = $ 1 [["category", "2"]]

Comment: Yes, thats the problem. I cant really detect why clicking on my categories still doesnt work when it shows its opening on the browser :/.